# meaning of `grad` parameter in tensorflow gradient functions (python)

Tags: tensorflow

What does the `grad` parameter in tensorflow gradient functions in python (like the example below from the docs) represent?

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("Sub")
def _sub_grad(unused_op, grad):
  return grad, tf.neg(grad)
```

The docs say it represents "the gradients with respect to each output of the op." Which gradients? The gradients of Each output of the op, with respect to each output of the op?

The op here is x - y. Does that mean the `grad` parameter in this function refers to

[image: grad]

?

This would be consistent with the output of the function, which is

[image],

but I wanted to make sure.

Thanks in advance for your clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read a great introduction to how backpropagation works in the CS231n notes [here](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/).

Each operation in the graph (in your exemple, `x-y`) has inputs and outputs. During backpropagation, the gradients flow from the output (beginning by the loss) towards the inputs.

Every gradient we compute in backpropagation is the gradient **of the loss** with respect to the parameter. So *"the gradients with respect to each output of the op."* means the gradient of the loss with respect to the outputs:

[image: gradients]

---

The outputs of the function are the gradients of the loss with respect to `x` and `y`:

[image: grads_x]

[image: grads_y]